# Determine whether the series converges absolutely, conditionally, or diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having lots of trouble with this series. I will upload a picture of what I did.

[image]

According to Wolfram, the series converges by the ratio test. I also don't know how I would use a different test for such a series. Two of the limits weren't difficult, but obviously I have to do something else, since I am not getting the right answer. We haven't covered Stirling approximation if it applies here, so I'd like some help without using it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You forgot the $10^{n^2}$ parts.

Comment: That limit is 0, so the whole limit is 0 as well. I can't believe it was right in front of me and I didn't see it. Thanks!